# Passing data to the Server with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying add textbox value into a table with button click.But I don't know ajax.please check my code.Is my ajax part correct? can anyone help me?

```
var roleList=[{
"no"     :"1",
"name":"xxx",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
},
{
"no"     :"2",
"name":"yyy",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
}
];

$(document).ready(function(){
       for(var i=0;i<roleList.length;i++)
       {
        var table='<tr><td>'+roleList[i].no+'</td><td>'+roleList[i].name+
        '</td><td><button class="btn dlt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'+roleList[i].dlt+'</button></td><tr>';
        $('#roleListTable').append(table)
       } 

});
```

I tried this:

```
   if (name != null) {
        $.post("",{empRoleList:roleList},
            function(data){
                if (data != 0) {
                                 alert("success");
                                 $('#name').each(function () {
                                     $(this).val('');
                                });
                                  var ajxObj = { name: "Personal", id: 0 };
                                  $.ajax({
                                     type: 'POST',
                                     url: "",
                                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                     data: JSON.stringify(ajxObj),
                                     dataType: 'html',
                                     success: function (response) {
                                         $('#roleListTable').html(response);
                                         // $('#grdUser').show();
                                     },
                                     failure: function (response) {
                                         alert(response.responseText);
                                     }
                                 });
                             }
                             else { alert("Fail"); }
                         });
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/95gnnpL1/1/

Comment: Why you want to do with ajax function?

Comment: You should just read some documentation, it's not hard at all

Comment: You can do this without ajax. Do want to fetch the data form database ?

Comment: @MinhajMimo yes my datas should be saved in database

Comment: @P.Frank In future I can use database for this.That is why I am trying with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var roleList=[{
"no"     :"1",
"name":"xxx",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
},
{
"no"     :"2",
"name":"yyy",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
}
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<roleList.length;i++)
    {
     var table='<tr><td>'+roleList[i].no+'</td><td>'+roleList[i].name+
     '</td><td><button class="btn dlt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'+roleList[i].dlt+'</button></td><tr>';
     $('#roleListTable').append(table)
    } 
  

  function submit(){
    var name = $(".name").val();
    var ajxObj = { name: name , id: 0 };
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(ajxObj),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
    $('#roleListTable').html(response);
    $('#rolesForm')[0].reset();
    co(resonse)
    },
    failure: function (response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
    }
    });
  }                           
   
});

//get the data and populate in the table
function getData(){

  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    type:'post'
    data: {},
    dataType: "json",
       cache: false,
    success: function (jsonResponse) {
    $.each(jsonResponse, function (key, val) { 
    var table='<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+val+
     '</td><tr>';
     $('#roleListTable').append(table)

   });
    }
    });
}
```

```html
<div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding">
                <form action=" " method="post" id="rolesForm">
             <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-x-2"> Name</label>
             <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 name">
             </form>
            </div>

             <div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding">
             <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-x-2">Description</label>
             <textarea type="text" name="description" id="description" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding pull">
                <span class="pull-right">
              <button class="btn save " id="save" onclick="submit"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Save
              </button>
     
    </span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   This may solve your problem..check the link..


  <html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var roleList=[{
                "no"     :"1",
                "name":"xxx",
                "dlt"     :"Delete"
                },
                {
                "no"     :"2",
                "name":"yyy",
                "dlt": "Delete"
                        }
                    ];
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        for (var i = 0; i < roleList.length; i++) {
                            var table = '<tr><td>' + roleList[i].no + '</td><td>' + roleList[i].name +
                                    '</td><td><button class="btn dlt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>' + roleList[i].dlt + '</button></td><tr>';
                            $('#roleListTable').append(table)
                        }
                        $('#save').on('click', function (e) {
                            var table = '<tr><td>' + $("#name").val() + '</td><td>' + $("#description").val() + '</td><tr>';
                            $('#roleListTable').append(table)
                        });
                    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="roleListTableHead">
                    <tr>
                        <td>no</td>
                        <td>emp id</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="roleListTable">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding">
            <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-x-2"> Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
        </div>

        <div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding">
            <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-x-2">Description</label>
            <textarea type="text" name="description" id="description" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding pull">
            <span class="pull-right">
                <button class="btn save " id="save" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#save"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Save
                </button>
                <button class="btn cancel "><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>Cancel</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/95gnnpL1/8/

Comment: @Doppa Srinivas Thanks.But I want to know using ajax how to do this.

Comment: @user7397787 please tell me your full requirement.I mean what you want to with ajax call..when you want to submit ajax request. And what is your inputs and what you want from ajax response.Then what you want to do with ajax response.

Comment: @DoppaSrinivas I have one table with json data and text box with save button,When I click save button after entering data in a text box that value should display in table as next row for this how can I write ajax code

Comment: @DoppaSrinivas please check I have updated one answer,this is for save data in a database. Similary how can i get data from database and display in a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can add textbox value into a table with button click like this.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add').on('click',function(){
   var name = $('#name').val(); //Getting the value of name field
   var description = $('#description').val(); //Getting the value of description field

   var tableData = '';

   tableData += '<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+description+'</td></tr>';

   $('#tbody').append(tableData);
  });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>jQuery Ajax</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <label for="description">Description:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter description">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tbody">

    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks can you tell me how to do this using ajax

Answer (score 0):

```js
var roleList=[{
"no"     :"1",
"name":"xxx",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
},
{
"no"     :"2",
"name":"yyy",
"dlt"     :"Delete"
}
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<roleList.length;i++)
    {
     var table='<tr><td>'+roleList[i].no+'</td><td>'+roleList[i].name+
     '</td><td><button class="btn dlt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'+roleList[i].dlt+'</button></td><tr>';
     $('#roleListTable').append(table)
    } 
  

  function submit(){
    var name = $(".name").val();
    var ajxObj = { name: name , id: 0 };
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(ajxObj),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
    $('#roleListTable').html(response);
    $('#rolesForm')[0].reset();
    co(resonse)
    },
    failure: function (response) {
    alert(response.responseText);
    }
    });
  }                           
   
});
```

```html
<div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding">
                <form action=" " method="post" id="rolesForm">
             <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-x-2"> Name</label>
             <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 name">
             </form>
            </div>

             <div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding">
             <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-x-2">Description</label>
             <textarea type="text" name="description" id="description" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding pull">
                <span class="pull-right">
              <button class="btn save " id="save" onclick="submit"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Save
              </button>
     
    </span>
            </div>
```